# QComboBox stylesheet not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: qt, combobox, qt5, stylesheet

I used a qss file to apply a theme to my application. It is cross platform. On Windows I can see my desired stylesheet as expected. As soon as I run  application on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with cinnamon desktop), I observed everything is fine, except combo box. Combo Box's pop up look as native ubuntu drop down. It is not showing as I expected. How to fix it

```
QComboBox
{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,30);
    border-radius:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    min-height:40px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    border:0px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width:25;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
    background-color:#424B54;
    border:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    outline: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item
{
    min-height:40px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255, 200);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:hover,QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:selected,QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:selected:hover
{
    min-height:40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 120);
    color: rgba(0,0,0);
}

/*QComboBox:on
{
    background-color:rgba(146, 39, 142, 255);
}*/

QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    border-image: url(:/Theme/theme/dark/general/down.png);
    padding:5px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on
{
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

**NOTE**
I observed QScrollBar as well taking native stylesheet

Comment: What is the output of `qDebug() << app->style()->metaObject().className();`? try with: `app.setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: not working. DcMainWindow window;
    window.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
    QSplashScreen s(QPixmap(":/Common/common/splashScreen.png"));